# CSS3 Transform not applying to all <a> elements as intended

Tags: css, hyperlink, hover, anchor, transition

In my header, I have this CSS specified.

```
a:link {
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    color:#3462D6;
}

a:visited {
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    color:#3462D6;
}

a:hover {
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    color:#82D1F7;
}

a:active {
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    color:#3462D6;  
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

For most of the links, the transitions are working, however links that I have visited do not play the animation in Chrome (And I would assume other webkit browsers as well)  Within Firefox however, all links do the transition animation just fine.

What could be the cause of the links not transitioning in Chrome?
The url is http://www.fuyuri.com

Comment: Didn't know you could do this effect, I've learnt something today! When you say visited do you mean clicked the link and returned? If so your only applying a colour using `:visited`

Comment: Yes.  Check my updated code.  Still suffering the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the active state above the hover state.  - link, visited, active, hover, focus and you need to apply the transitions to all states. Transitions are not inherited.

Comment: I've done as you've stated, however the error is still occurring.  Yes, I've been sure to clear my cache.

Comment: Also, my XHTML class and research says that the order is "link, visited, hover, active"

Comment: Edited my original post to reflect my new code changes, still suffering the same errors.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, your edited code doesn't show transitions in the various states. CSS3 transition is not an inherited property. You need add all the transitions to all elements you wish to have transitions. (http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-transitions/)

Comment: It acts as inherited, and even if I add it to all of them it still behaves exactly the same.  "visited" will not get it, no matter what I do.

Works fine in Firefox, not in Webkit.

Comment: I'll go ahead and edit my code to follow spec, but I wish I could figure out what was going on here.

Comment: Very odd. I can't get the color to transition for chrome either (see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DG5Hw/) Might be a bug in Chrome.

Comment: You're right.  I didn't even think that color could be the only issue.  What about other webkit browsers, like Safari?  Does the same bug exist?

For now, I'm just going to shove in a jQuery workaround.  Thank you for the help!